# Undefined local variable or method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my ruby on rails project, I found this error in `update`.

```
undefined local variable or method ` ' for #<ProfileController:0x007fd904dc8568>.
```

However, I can't find **(` ')** in my controller.

**ProfileController#update**

```
def update       
   unless params[:sport_name].nil? 
     ps_array = params[:sport_name]
     level =[params[:level1],params[:level2],params[:level3]]
     # play_sports id 
     sp_id = [params[:sp_id1], params[:sp_id2], params[:sp_id3]]

     arr = [ps_array["1"],ps_array["2"],ps_array["3"]]
     sport_id = [params[:sport_id1],params[:sport_id2],params[:sport_id3]]
     check = [params[:check1], params[:check2], params[:check3]]

     if @user.play_sports.count != 0

       (0..2).each do |i|
           if (check[i].to_i == 1)
           PlaySport.where("id = ?", sp_id[i]).update_all(:is_active=>false)
           # new save 
           newuser_ps = PlaySport.new
           newuser_ps.sport_id = arr[i]
           newuser_ps.is_active = true
           newuser_ps.level = level[i]
           newuser_ps.user_id = current_user.id
           newuser_ps.save
         end
       end
     else         
       (0..2).each do |i|    
         newuser_ps = PlaySport.new
         newuser_ps.sport_id = arr[i]
         newuser_ps.level = level[i]
         newuser_ps.is_active = true
         newuser_ps.user_id = current_user.id
         newuser_ps.save
       end
     end        
   end


   respond_to do |format|        
   end
end
```

Comment: On `which line it is giving error`???can you `mention that line` here `instead` of all the `update` method

Comment: That's a single method?!

Comment: Ok . I change my code - the error show at                           if @user.play_sports.count != 0          
(0..2).each do |i|

Comment: when update button click , coding error not found .  but I see ` ' this.It is not in my controller.I can't find these ` '.

Comment: That's just quotes around what ruby thinks the error is, it doesn't mean those quotes are in your code.

Comment: Check for "strange" characters there, if you delete and re-type those three lines (and remove threw second blank line) what happens?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably an invisible character that you see as space, but ruby don't. Check by selecting the text in a decent editor, which would show whether they are spaces or other.